# How to have extra django model fields depending on the value of a field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model in my Django project called `Job`. Each Job has a category. An example of a category could be **tutoring**. This can be represented as what my model looks like right now:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class Job(models.Model):

    # Abbreviations for possible categories to be stored in the database.
    TUTORING = "TU"
    PETSITTING = "PS"
    BABYSITTING = "BS"
    INTERIOR_DESIGN = "IND"
    SHOPPING = "SH"
    SOFTWARE_DEVELOPMENT = "SD"
    DESIGN = "DE"
    ART = "AR"
    HOUSEKEEPING = "HK"
    OTHER = "OT"

    JOB_CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        (TUTORING, 'Tutoring'),
        (PETSITTING, "Petsitting"),
        (BABYSITTING, "Babysitting"),
        (INTERIOR_DESIGN, "Interior Design"),
        (SHOPPING, "Shopping"),
        (SOFTWARE_DEVELOPMENT, "Software Development"),
        (DESIGN), "Design"),
        (ART, "Art"),
        (HOUSEKEEPING, "Housekeeping"),
        (OTHER, "Other"),
    )

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=JOB_CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=OTHER,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Depending on the category of the Job, different fields are required. For example, if I take tutoring as the category again, then extra fields like `address`, `subject`, level of study and others are needed. If the category of the Job is software development however, extra fields like `project_size` and `required_qualifications` are needed.

Should I create a separate model for each type of Job or is there some kind of model inheritance I can use where job types inherit from the main Job model which holds all the common fields that all Jobs need.

Essentially, what is the best way to have extra fields depending on the Job category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options:

#### 1. `OneToOneField` on various category models:

- Pro: 
  allows other models to have FK to `Job` model. E.g. you could retrieve all of a person jobs via `person.jobs.all()` no matter which category.
- Con: 
  Allows instances of different categories to relate to the same Job instance: Extra work is needed to maintain data integrity

  More tables, more joins, slower queries

  Adding a category always entails a migration!

#### 2. `Multi-Table` inheritance:

Uses `OneToOneField` under the hood.

- Pro: 
  as above + but each instance of a category will autocreate its own `Job` instance, so no collisions between categories.
- Con:
  More tables, more joins, slower queries. Obscures some of the db stuff that's going on.

  Adding a category always entails a migration!

#### 3. `Job` as an abstract base model

- Pro: Single table for each category, faster queries
- Con: separate relations need to be maintained for each category, no grouping possible at the db level.

  Adding a category always entails a migration!

#### 4. Put all the category specific fields in `Job` (and make them nullable)

- Pro: One Table, easy relations, Queries for special categories via filter on `category` field still possible.

  You can use specific model managers to handle categories: `Job.tutoring.all()`

  Possibly many categories share various subsets of fields

  No overengineering, easy maintainability.

  Adding a new category will only require a migration if it requires a field that is not there yet. You could have a generic `CharField` used by multiple categories for different semantic purposes and access it via `propertys` with meaningful names. These cannot, however, be used in filters or qs-updates.

À la:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    # ...
    attribute = models.CharField(...)

    def _get_attribute(self):
        return self.attribute

    def _set_attribute(self, value):
        self.attribute = value

    # for shopping
    shop_name = property(_get_attribute, _set_attribute)

    # for babysitting
    family_name = property(_get_attribute, _set_attribute)

# then you can use
babysitting_job.family_name = 'Miller'
```

- Con: Some fields are null for each job

While options 1-3 may better model the real world and make you feel good about the sophisticated model structure you have cooked up, I would not discard option 4 too quickly.

If the category fields are few and commonly shared between categories, this would be my way to go.

Comment: To be honest option 4 seems the best and most efficient. When you say specific model managers, do you mean like this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/, which control the query set returned. What is the point in model managers if I can just filter via the `category` field? Also, how would you implement a generic CharField used by multiple categories to be accessed by `properties` with meaningful names?

Comment: You can filter on `category` of course. The managers will just be shortcuts for these filters and their usefulness depends on the frequency you use such category filters. Added some explanation for the other question.

Comment: Dont you need to add decorators to the _get_attribute and _set_attribute functions? Where does the babysitting_job come from?

Comment: No. You define the properties underneath. You can use the `property` and `property.setter` decorators, but you would have to do it for each name individually. This way you define one generic setter/getter pair and can then define properties with useful names in a single line.

Comment: Where does the babysitting_job come from though?

Comment: Just some exemplary `Job` instance ;)

Comment: This last line would be written in a view, correct?

Comment: Yeah. In a view, in the shell or anywhere else in your project! (well, not in a template, actually)

Comment: When it comes to querying the Job model, how will I exclude the null fields not associated to the job category?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133747/discussion-between-schwobaseggl-and-tom-finet).

Answer (score 0):

The optimal thing to do would be to use a OneToOneField. Before further explanation, I'll just use this example:

```
    from django.db import models

    class Menu(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


    class Item(models.Model):
        menu = models.OneToOneField(Menu)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Menu here could compare to your Job model. Once an item in the menu is chosen, the Menu model basically extends the chosen Item's fields. Item here can be compared to your Job category.

You can read more on this stuff [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/).

Comment: What about multi-table inheritance? Would this work: https://godjango.com/blog/django-abstract-base-class-multi-table-inheritance/

Comment: @TomFinet multi-table inheritance (or inheriting from a concrete model) works via a `OneToneField` that is implicitly created, so not much difference there. It does give you some convenience like accessing or filtering the base model's fields directly, but it also obscures some of the stuff that's happening under the hood.